# How to make an object that has display:hidden appear as display:block when another image that is visible is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, dom-events

What I want to accomplish is the effect I have seen in this site

[www.press75.com](http://www.press75.com)

That is when you click on any of the theme images ex. Hoon or Brocco an expansion on what the theme appears below.
I have seen the code with firebug

and I see this:

```
<div id="theme-gallery" class="content">
<div id="261" class="thumbnail">
<div id="more-info-261" class="hidden">
```

and when you click on any of them a div appears with the `display:"block";`

```
<div id="theme-gallery" class="content">
<div id="261" class="thumbnail">
<div id="more-info-261" class="hidden">
<div id="42" class="thumbnail">
<div id="message" class="more-info sevenfive-message" style="display: block;">
<div id="more-info-42" class="hidden">
```

I get how to make something hidden and blocked but I don't know how to make it so that when the image gets clicked the description image changes from hidden to block  is this done with Javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with jquery or javascript. Options include:

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(e){$(e.target).next().show();});

$('.thumbnail').click(function(e){
    $('#more-info-' + $(e.target).attr('id')).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

In either case, you will need to assign a click event handler to each thumbnail, select that thumbnail's description, and then reveal it by either removing the class "hidden" (which, presumably sets `display: none`) or explicitly calling jQuery's `show` function.

For what it's worth, I'd recommend implementing it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#theme-gallery").on("click", ".thumbnail", showDescription);
});
function showDescription(e){
    $('#more-info-' + $(e.target).attr('id')).removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to assign the event handler would keep you from having as many event handlers flying around and would attach itself to any thumbnails loaded into the theme gallery (through AJAX, for example).  It also removes the hidden class, which is, in my opinion, much cleaner and usually faster.

Comment: Ok I would just need to learn a some jquery know any book or site that teaches how to implement this. Thanks :)

Comment: The explanations at http://api.jquery.com are quite good, actually.  That, stackoverflow, and google are your best friends there.  Areas you'll want to look at will be selectors (which look like $('css-syntax selector') and are how jQuery moves through the DOM), the element attribute accessor function ($('selector').attr('attribute name')), the element class mutator functions (which are $('selector').addClass('className') and $('selector").removeClass('className')), and on (which binds events to a node/its select descendents, look at jQuery events and the click function for background).